# Encrypt and decrypt sensitive properties in DTO

Tags: c#, encryption, entity-framework-core

I have a WebApi application. It contains data which are basically ID which comes as plain text. I want to Encrypt all the ID fields whenever it is pushed to API responses. At the same time I want to Decrypt the same data when I'm pushing to Entity.

What I have done now.

I am using Automapper to map my DTO and Entity. I have made methods to encrypt and decrypt the data.

**DTO Model**

```
public class MyDTO
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Property1 {get; set; }
  public string Property2 { get; set; }
  public int AnotherModelId { get; set }
}
```

**My AutoMapper**

```
//Encrypting Id for DTO
CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDTO>()
                .ForMember(o => o.Id, i => i.MapFrom(m => MySecurity.Encrypt(m.Id)))
                .ForMember(o => o.AnotherModelId, i => i.MapFrom(m => MySecurity.Encrypt(m.AnotherModelId)));

//Decrypting Id for Entity
CreateMap<MyDTO, MyEntity>()
                .ForMember(o => o.Id, i => i.MapFrom(m => MySecurity.Decrypt(m.Id)))
                .ForMember(o => o.AnotherModelId, i => i.MapFrom(m => MySecurity.Decrypt(m.AnotherModelId)));
```

This works perfectly and encrypts the Id's I mention in the mappers and decrypts when I pass the value back to the entity. The problem is I need to write it for every `CreateMap<>` statement I'm using.

My question is, there definitely must be a better way to do this encryption and decryption for the Id fields in .NET

I saw the `[SecureString]` attribute, which says "Do not use" by everyone. So I don't want to use that.

Is there a better way to write this in the Model and Entity model itself than in Automapper or another way?

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to protect against? Protecting the HTTP data is the web framework's job, not the ORM's. All web APIs use HTTPS by default. Besides, where are you going to keep the encryption key? HTTPS takes care of that already, through certificates

Comment: I know the HTTPS will manage the data passed through traffic, but I dont want the plain data to be shown even in hidden fields on my front end where someone can guess the ID and start playing with ID's

Comment: So the real question is about security, not encryption. Encryption doesn't help if you don't have proper server-side security. Nothing prevent the end user from viewing the web site's JS source, reading the keys and finding out how to decrypt the IDs. Nothing prevents them from replaying IDs or trying random IDs until something works. If you don't want IDs to be accessible on the browser, don't send them at all. Use a *different* web DTO

Comment: how am i going to know what i am sending if i cannot identify my record with any other means? i need some sort of identification coming from FE if i need to do some actions with those right? I wanted encryption to i can make sure the IDs are not plaintext in my form if anyone tries to play with it

Answer (score 2):

Create a base class for all those classes that would need encryption:

```
public class Encryptable
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        set
       {
           _id = MySecurity.Encrypt(value);
       }
       get
       {
            return MySecurity.Decrypt(_id);
       } 
    }
}
```

Now inherit all classes you want their Id to be encrypted:

```
public class MyDTO: Encryptable
{
    ....
}
```

Now you may use automapper as you would normally do (with no need to encrypt and decrypt), and let the class itself handle that for you.

Comment: Who's going to handle the key? The correct answer here is *not through the ORM* and definitely not AutoMapper. Encrypting the API responses is the controller's job. Assuming any kind of encryption beyond TLS1.2 is really needed.  Encrypting the data is the database's job

Comment: I just wrote the solution that OP wants to achieve

Comment: That doesn't make this a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

First... You should probably start with securing the web application itself, by setting TLS and http security headers. (I'd recommend you to check securityheaders.com for a quick overview on the possibilities)

Second... Aside from that. If you really must encrypt these keys, then I'd probably choose a combination of an interface for identifying the ids and write a custom JsonConverter for these DTOs (-->this interface), that takes care of the encryption/decryption.

Microsoft has a pretty good documentation for this in .Net 6.

[How to write custom converters for JSON serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to)

Third: If you dont want the ids to be guessable, you should use GUIDs. They can even be used as identities by EF core.